# Functionals. $L^2(a,b)\subset L^1(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I have to show that, for $a,b\in \mathbb{R},\ a<b$, we have $L^2(a,b)\subset L^1(a,b)$.

I do not know where to start.

Comment: Or you could use the inequality $|f(x)|\le 1+|f(x)|^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f \in L^2 (a,b)$, then by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have $$(\int^{b}_{a} |f| dx)^2 \le (\int^{b}_{a} 1^2 dx)(\int^{b}_{a} |f|^2 dx)$$ hence the result.